# mysql, copy from one field to another

Tags: mysql, copy

I have a MySql database, I want to copy everything that is in the "topic_last_post_subject" field into the "phpbb_topics" fields, if the "phpbb_topics" field is blank.  I would like to use the phpMyAdmin SQL query tool to do this.  I am not that familiar with the correct syntax, is this correct?

```
UPDATE `phpbb_topics` SET `topic_title`=`topic_last_post_subject`;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query will update ALL rows.  You only want to update the blank ones:

```
UPDATE phpbb_topics SET topic_title = topic_last_post_subject
WHERE topic_title IS NULL OR
      topic_title = '';
```

Comment: Worked perfectly (except the typo in the table name) - many thanks!